# How to embed my vuejs app to external website?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i'm trying to embed an app with vuejs but i haven't found a way to make it work.

what I want to achieve is to be able to publish the app easily on customer pages by adding one or two lines of code (include the js file and the call).

This is my main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

const app = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

I tried to make a build and insert the compiled source at a html+js new project but it doesn't render the components(only shows the layout but without initializing the app)

Another option that I am evaluating, is to convert the components to web components to be able to receive configuration values and that the content varies according to these

Comment: You might have an easier time of this with the CDN version of Vue assuming you're not doing anything too complex